# Spring Session, Embedded Redis Server Error

Tags: redis, spring-session

Unable to start embedded Redis server, its giving the following error. What could be the possible reason. I'm working on Wildfly, Ubuntu. Following is the stacktrace.

> ... 25 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisServer' defined in org.egov.infra.config.session.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't start redis server. Check logs for details.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
>       ... 27 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't start redis server. Check logs for details.
>       at redis.embedded.AbstractRedisInstance.awaitRedisServerReady(AbstractRedisInstance.java:66)
>       at redis.embedded.AbstractRedisInstance.start(AbstractRedisInstance.java:37)
>       at redis.embedded.RedisServer.start(RedisServer.java:11)
>       at org.egov.infra.config.redis.EmbeddedRedisServer.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedRedisServer.java:20)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been reported here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/150

Comment: hmmm... but its started when i installed and tested first later it got stop working then i moved embedded redis of clojar to orange latest then its working fine. But i have noticed some abnormal issue with spring data redis is trying to serialize my entity object (i'm not intended to use spring-data-redis anything apart for spring-session, any insight ?).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running embedded redis-server on port 1337 and this port was locked and went into a loop sometime back when I was running my testcases in debug mode. After that I also started spring-boot app which created another server connection on the port 6379. But I failed to terminate the server running on the port 1337. Since then I had been getting the exception when I was trying to execute test cases "Can't start redis server. Check logs for details.", since 1337 was locked. Debugging line-my-line "AbstractRedisInstance" class and "awaitRedisServerReady" method revealed "1337 Already in use" which was never logged at all. Killed this port and re-run testcases and again I was on fly. Hope this helps

Comment: Please format the answer. Please check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)